# Livereload of ionic 2 with docker-compose instance does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, ionic2, livereload

In a project I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:6.9.4
RUN npm install -g cordova@4.2.0 ionic@2.2.1
ENV DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP=/web-app
RUN mkdir -p $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP
ADD . $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP
WORKDIR $DOCKER_CONTAINER_APP
EXPOSE 8100 35729
RUN echo "ready to go!"
```

I am using docker-compose, and this is the `docker-compose yml` file I use in my project:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - DEBUG='true'
    ports:
     - 8100:8100
     - 35729:35729
    volumes:
     - .:/web-app
     - ./node_modules:/web-app/node_modules
    command: sh -c 'npm install; ionic serve --all'
    stdin_open: true
```

All works well, this is the output of a docker-compose run web command:

```
[10:53:11]  ionic-app-scripts 1.0.0 
[10:53:18]  watch started ... 
[10:53:18]  build dev started ... 
[10:53:18]  clean started ... 
[10:53:18]  clean finished in 57 ms 
[10:53:18]  copy started ... 
[10:53:18]  transpile started ... 
[10:53:36]  transpile finished in 17.96 s 
[10:53:36]  webpack started ... 
[10:53:37]  copy finished in 19.39 s 
[10:53:51]  webpack finished in 15.10 s 
[10:53:51]  sass started ... 
[10:53:56]  sass finished in 4.90 s 
[10:53:56]  build dev finished in 38.18 s 
[10:53:57]  watch ready in 39.27 s 
[10:53:57]  dev server running: http://localhost:8100/
```

But the native ionic **livereload** does not work. How can I use the Livereload with this ionic docker image ?

Answer (score 4):

When I had similar issue I'd noticed in browser failed attempts to contact port 53703. Here is screenshot:
[Chrome developer tools window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yGOG.png)

Container I used at that moment had been created with command

```
docker run -i -t -d --name ionic-dev -v /home/timur/Work/:/Work/ \
       -p 8100:8100 -p 35729:35729 ionic-dev
```

So I stopped and deleted it

```
docker stop ionic-dev
docker rm ionic-dev
```

And created another container with command (notice published port 53703)

```
docker run -i -t -d --name ionic-dev -v /home/timur/Work/:/Work/ \
       -p 8100:8100 -p 35729:35729 -p 53703:53703 ionic-dev
```

After that livereload started to work for me.

Comment: describe your answer some more

Comment: @timur thank you for your answer, could you please be more specific, writing an example. It could helps us.

Comment: @IsuruAb I've changed my answer to give more details about my workaround